# Conditionally Setting Line Color

Tags: filemaker

In FileMaker 11 Pro, is there a way to conditionally set the color of a line?

Background: I'm trying to conditionally set the color of a border around a section of my layout based on the value of a field. This border is made up of line segments.

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hack something together by setting the fill color of very narrow or short elements. Not a very appealing solution.

I noticed that if there's an "embossed" or "engraved" on a field with a conditional fill color, the fill color is reflected in the 3d border effect. Would this be an option?

Answer (score 1):

Text blocks can be conditionally filled with colour using conditional formatting. Strategic placement of a text block behind a filled rectangle can make it appear to be a border.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, Vaughan. If I were to use it and print the output to a PDF, wouldn't the "hidden" text be included in the PDF (perhaps having the same color as the background and so not readily visible but nevertheless there)?